# HighCharts Create gradiance decress color to blur for each value on bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create some high carts bar with gradient decrees for each bar
bar decrees color become blurry for each range, for rank 1 bar the color is solid

this is my sample picture

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colorAxis` from `heatmap` series by wrapping colum's prototype:

```
var columnProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype;

columnProto.axisTypes = ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis'];
columnProto.optionalAxis = 'colorAxis';
columnProto.colorKey = 'y';

Highcharts.wrap(columnProto, 'translate', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    Highcharts.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }],
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#c6e48b',
        maxColor: '#196127',
        min: 1,
        max: 9
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u8wgh0dk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

Comment: thank @ppotaczek, but my data about thousand, hot to set max and min base on data?

Comment: Hi @RAVI BANGKIT NUR ZIKRILLAH, You need to set `min` and `max` properties according to your data in a `colorAxis` configuration object: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1zj79odv/